# How to show openstreetmap using Mapsui?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, maps, openstreetmap, mapsui

I'm trying to use openstreetmap in my xamarin.forms app using mapsui;

Tried this tutorial https://mapsui.com/documentation/getting-started-xamarin-forms.html

But the Android displays a  [Application Not Responding dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HXMOc.png)
. I don't know why ,but when I remove the code in MainPage.xaml.cs the program works but doesn't show the map, all it shows is: [image Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RKpaj.png)

if there is any other tutorial please let me know

the code that i removed :

```html
var map = new Map
{
    CRS = "EPSG:3857",
    Transformation = new MinimalTransformation()
};

var tileLayer = OpenStreetMap.CreateTileLayer();

map.Layers.Add(tileLayer);
map.Widgets.Add(new Widgets.ScaleBar.ScaleBarWidget(map) { TextAlignment = Widgets.Alignment.Center, HorizontalAlignment = Widgets.HorizontalAlignment.Left, VerticalAlignment = Widgets.VerticalAlignment.Bottom });

mapView.Map = map;
```

Comment: if the page is crashing, either add some exception handling logic or use the debugger to track down the cause and then fix it.

Comment: "remove the code in MainPage.xaml.cs" - perhaps if you posted this code we could give you some specific advice?

Comment: actually visual studio doesn't crush . but when i run the programme in android emulator, it shows  " X close app" notification

Comment: if it doesn't actually crash then you shouldn't describe it as a crash in your question.  Android displays a Application Not Responding dialog when an app is hung.  You should do some basic debugging of your app to determine which line is hanging.